# How to insert bulky value to sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add bulky data from another data below. But I can not do that: error is returned. But areas are the same as another.

```
declare @hrmtable1 table(musterino int, ekno smallint)

insert into @hrmtable1 (musterino , ekno)
    select distinct musterino, ekno
    from hareketmuhasebe (nolock) 
    where islemtarihi >= '20120101'
      and isnull(musterino, 0) <> 0 
      and isnull(musterino, 0) > 9000000 
      and isnull(ekno,0) <> 0 

insert into table1(A,B,C,D,E,. . . . .N) 
   SELECT DISTINCT 
      case when ((select count(*) from table1 where musterino=e.musterino) > 0)
           then (select top 1 *
                 from dbo.table1 
                 where musterino = e.musterino  
                 order by ekno desc)
           else 
                (select 100, e.musterino, e.ekno, 0, K, L, M)
                 from @hrmtable1 e )
      end
```

ERROR:

> *Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list.
>
>   The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.*

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Since you edited the question, still the answer remains the same. Your number of columns in Select statement doesn't match to your insert statement columns in the 2nd part of your code.

In your first statement you are specifying `2` columns and in select you have `5` columns, they should match and that is what the error is telling you exactly.

```
insert into @hrmtable1 (musterino , ekno)
                         ^^^^^^^    ^^^^
select distinct musterino,ekno,defterid,dovizcinsi, subekodu
                ^^^^^^^    ^^^   ^^^^     ^^^^^      ^^^^^
```

From your `insert` statement it looks like you don't need the last three columns in your `Select` statement.

Comment: @programmerist, then make sure that your query `select top 1 *
 from dbo.table1` returns the same number of columns as your insert statement or your other select statement

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in  the error the number of columns in insert does not mach the number of value that you are providing

```
insert into @hrmtable1 (musterino , ekno)
select distinct musterino,ekno
from hareketmuhasebe (nolock) 
where islemtarihi >= '20120101'
and isnull(musterino,0) <> 0 and isnull(musterino,0) < 9000000 and isnull(ekno,0) <> 0
```

Comment: Check the same in your same query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into @hrmtable1 (musterino , ekno)
select distinct musterino,ekno
from hareketmuhasebe (nolock) 
where islemtarihi >= '20120101'
and isnull(musterino,0) <> 0 and isnull(musterino,0) < 9000000 and isnull(ekno,0) <> 0
```

You are having 2 columns in insert & 5 columns in select clause, that is the cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the
>   insert list.  The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

*The error itself tells you the story that what you are doing wrong*. you have fewer columns in insert statement than to select statement.

From **MSDN**

> The select list of the subquery must match the column list of the
>   INSERT statement. If no column list is specified, the select list must
>   match the columns in the table or view being inserted into.

Read more about [Inert into](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/10/sql-server-use-insert-into-select-instead-of-cursor/)